# Play store error #963

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services, xiaomi, miui

I have a Xiaomi redmi note 4, last week, I flash super su with TWRP, I change the sd mount to EXT4 because I have a problem, but is solved, and I wipe data. When I reboot the phone to system, all is OK, but I can't install any apk from play store, I get the error 903. I try to wipe data, wipe play store cache, uninstall the updates, reinstall play store, wipe data of google play services, etc... But nothing works. Right now im using Aptoide, please help, thanks you.

[image: Error code: 963]

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! For explanations on the 905, please consult our [google-play-store tag-wiki](/tags/google-play-store/info), which already lists this. I've adjusted the title to only point to the 963 (which is also shown in your screenshot), as a question should only address one issue (be welcome to open another one for the 903 if needed).

Answer (score 2):

When using the methods reported by @Izzy, none of them solved the issue on my Galaxy On7, rooted to work with Android Pie (9), LineageOS 16 flavour -- using an SD Card as adopted storage.

Here is what I did:

1. After enabling Developer Options, I checked the option "Force Allow apps on external" [image: the image showing the force allow apps on the external development option]
2. Cleared the play store data;
3. Rebooted the device

Now all apps on playstore, which I had forcibly moved to the sd card with Titanium Backup, are able to be updated with no issues.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The complete error message reads:

> {App Name} could not be downloaded due to an error (963).

(just writing this for the benefit of those who cannot understand the language in your screenshot). According to [this post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/YbLdvD9Z7Aw) on Google's product forum, there are multiple approaches to solve the underlying issue:

1. uninstall updates of the *Google Play Store* app
2. clearing cache and data of the *Google Play Store* app
3. unmount and remount the SD card
4. using the sd card as internal storage (see: [adoptable-storage](/questions/tagged/adoptable-storage))
5. moving apps which are installed on the card to internal storage
6. remove the Google account from the device and then add it back

Detailed instructions for each of those methods can be found behind the link above.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if you move or delete a large file (or a few small ones) then you should be able to download and install the app. This has worked for me and works for all of the 900-1000 error codes. I have not encountered all of them so it might not work for some but it does work for this one.

To move correctly
Just move a file to a different storage to the instalation storage.

To move a file go into settings》Storage》Applications (or another catagory)》X》Storage
Then press change to successfully move a file

X=File of choice